# Stereo volume control in headphone amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I have a headphone amplifier schematic and I want to make it in stereo. My questions are:

- Is there any way to realize the volume control with one potentiometer,
  or should I use some kind of dual gang type?
- Do I have to use a logarithmic or linear one?
- If you have time I'd appreciate a short summary of the operation of the circuit.

Thanks, Tamas

Amplifier:

[image: Amplifier circuit]

Power supply:

[image: Power supply]

Answer (score 1):

This is a Class A amplifier - the output transistor is always conducting until the amplifier reaches negative clip.

It doesn't have much output power and worse yet, the amount of available negative current becomes less as the amp output swings negative.

It should drive headphones just fine but that's about it.

If you want to use a pair of these as a stereo pair, you will want to use an audio-taper dual pot for the volume control.